# Unable to open file on Spyder

Tags: python, filesystems, spyder

For my school project, I have to open a file and perform functions based on it, and I am having issues accessing the file. The file is called text.txt and I have initialized the function correctly.
I keep getting an error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'" Both files are in the same folder, so it should be able to seamlessly access it but it's failing.
The code and screenshots are attached below.

Code:

```
def cleanse(filename):
    file=open(filename,'r')
    content=file.readline()
    file.close()
    return content
def main():
    print(cleanse('file.txt'))
main()
```

error message and path: [image: error message and path]

Comment: I know you mentioned them being in the same folder, but can you just double-check with `os.listdir()`? Also, you could alternatively try to use the absolute path

Comment: Make sure you are calling your script from the same directory where your files are.